# Let $f$ be a continous function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $x(t)$ be of class $C^1$ given by the solution of: >$x' - f(x) = t^2$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I can't find a way to solve this one, although it seems to be quite basic:

> Let $f$ be a continous function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $x(t)$ be of class $C^1$ given by the solution of:
>
> $x' - f(x) = t^2$
>
> Knowing that $x(0) = x_0 \geq 0$ and $f(0) > 0$ prove that if $t > 0 $ then $ x(t) > 0$. Is it true if $ t < 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on LutzL's hint I've prepared a solution (in case anyone is interested):

As $f(0) > 0$ and $f$ is continous function there is $\epsilon > 0$ such as $\forall_{y \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)} f(y) > 0$, thus $\forall_t\, x(t) \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \implies x'(t) = t^2 + f(x(t)) > 0$. So whenever the $x(t)$ reaches 0 its derivative becomes positive and the function grows out of the $\epsilon$ ball.

As $x(0) \geq 0$ and $x$ is a continous function $\forall_{t>0} x(t) > 0$.

On the other if $t<0$ it is possible that $x(t) < 0$ - when $t \in (-\infty, z) $ where $z$ is first such point that $x(z) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that whenever $x(t)$ is close to $0$, then $x'(t)$ is positive and thus the solution is growing away from the $x$ axis.